# Setup Restund in Google Compute Engine

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I am new to WebRTC. I would like to set a TURN/STUN server. I found restund but there is no proper documentation on how to install it on ubuntu. Are there any good tutorials for setting up Restund or any other Turn/Stun server.